# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite3-binary (from versions: none)"

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm working on a login page for a desktop app I'm developing. I'm trying to install the latest version of pysqlite3 on Visual Studio Code for python as the one I have in my program, sqlite3, is deprecated. I figured it was necessary as I didn't know if keeping the old version could cause some errors in the database that I'm creating.

However, every attempt would result this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite3-binary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysqlite3-binary
```

Are there any solutions to this?

Here's the code that I'm using to create the database with sqlite:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error 
   
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
   
   
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    create_connection(r"C:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\pydataview\views\database\storage.db")
```

One recommended method I was told do use was the command `pip install chromadb==0.3.29` but it gave me an error by the end, saying that it couldn't build the wheels for hnswlib, so I'm not really sure if it helped enough.

Comment: Can you include the complete error message you get in your question?